# How to control output of 'tree -F' command?

Tags: command-line, bash, tree

I'm using the 'tree' command to create a text file that I parse in Libre Office Calc:

`tree -ifsD --timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %T" $PWD > dirlist_tree.txt`

I added the '-F' option to add a '/' to the end of directory lines in order to help Calc with the parsing:

`tree -F -ifsD --timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %T" $PWD > dirlist_tree.txt`

From what I've been able to find so far, there are three additional characters that this option might add to the output. At least one of them is causing me some problems, hence, this question:

How can I limit the `tree -F` command such that it will only add '/' to directory lines and no others, like '=' or '|' or '*', which it is currently doing?

thanks,

BabaG

Answer (score 1):

To parse `tree` output, you should use machine readable output, e.g. `json` with `tree -J`:

E.g. parsing to CSV using `Python`, to directly open in Libre Office Calc:

### `tree_to_csv.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json,sys,csv
data = json.load(sys.stdin)

elements = []

def get_element(el):
    global elements
    if "size" in el:
        elements.append(el)
    if el["type"] == "directory":
        for sub_el in el["contents"]:
            get_element(sub_el)

for el in data: 
    get_element(el)

fieldnames = ['size', 'time', 'name']
writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')

writer.writeheader()

for el in elements:
    if el["type"] == "directory":
        el["name"] += '/'
    writer.writerow(el)
```

### Run:

```
tree -Jsf  --timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %T" | python tree_to_csv.py
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this, pLumo. It's a lot more than I was expecting. I was hoping to keep my process more or less as-is rather than changing to calling a python script. I was hoping there might be some simple qualifier I could add that would tell '-F' to omit '=', '|', and '*'  and only apply '/' to directory lines. This will take me a lot of rethinking as I'm not much of a scripter/programmer.